# Are JS Promises, processor-like parallelism?

Tags: javascript, promise

I was reading about the [JS Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) and since they are generally

> extremely useful for async success/failure, because you're less interested in the exact time something became available, and more interested in reacting to the outcome.

I couldn't not to remember about the way processors "pipeline" their instruction execution in order to get a degree of parallelism. In short

> Processor chips can execute instructions in parallel. But how do you take a stream of machine instructions intended to be executed serially and divide them up into parallel streams that make sense? The way processors do this is very clever and quite complex, but in essence they often come to points where they effectively "guess" the result of an operation in a separate execution pipeline and start executing on the assumption of that guess. If the guess is later found to be wrong, the results of the stream that was based on it are simply dumped. There has been no gain—but no loss either. However, if the guess was good, the processor has just done twice as much work in the time it would take a single stream of execution—so for that spell, it was running twice as fast.

My question is - does JS Promises implement the same concept?

Comment: kinda. the main thread that promises run on is single-threaded, so it only does one thing at once. however, the waiting part of a promise is usually because of IO, which often runs on a different thread. if i dispatch 4 promises to fetch different resources, they could actually all be executing at once. once they complete, then it's back to a one-at-a-time single thread operation...

Comment: No. Unlike a pipeline, a promise does represent the *result* of an asynchronous action. It doesn't even say anything about parallelism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not parallel processing as promises can be on a single thread and there is no concept of task parallelization built into them, they arent going to break a problem down into parallel subtasks etc. They are solely a method to respond to and manage asynchronous events.

The best mock I could think of to mimic parallelism would require the user to break their problem down  into parallizable tasks and then pass each call to a Promise.All type function which would use webworkers to handle the invocations. Most likely a useless exercise as you are basically just decorating webworkers with promises. You'd be much better advised to leverage a library like [parallel.js](http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/) in cases like this.

Comment: Parallel.js Library can be accessed here: https://parallel.js.org/

Answer (score 4):

Promises really has nothing to do with processor parallelism.  Promises are a software concept that lives many, many levels above the processor.  In Javascript, it would be the Javascript run-time engine that would or would not take advantage of how processors can run certain things in parallel and an implementation of promises many levels above that would not influence that in any way.

Promises are a software architecture for keeping track of asynchronous activities, registering an interest in their completion (or failure), and coordinating those asynchronous activities with other activities.  The use of asynchronous activities allows the system to have more than one activity "in-flight" at the same time (such as downloading an image while also waiting for the response to an ajax call while also responding to user events).  But, this ability to use asynchronous activities is not unique to promises and is not related to processor parallelism.

Promises do not, by themselves, break any task up into a parallel actions.  If you break your own task up into multiple asynchronous pieces, then promises allow you to manage those asynchronous activities and results in a structured way.